# How to create the following usage with TCLAP?

Tags: c++, command-line

I’m trying to create the following usage `{-l <string> [--no_flush] | -o <string> | -p}`. I tried the following but I cannot force “no_flush” be used only with “-l”. The code below gives me `{-l <lut_filename> | -o <out_dir>| -p} [--no_flash]`
How do I do this?

```
ValueArg<string> lutArg("l", "lut", "Set LUT", true, "", "lut_filename");
SwitchArg noLUTFlashSwitch("", "no_flash", "Do not flash LUT");
cmd.add(noLUTFlashSwitch);

ValueArg<string> lutOutArg("o", "out_lut", "Dump LUT values", true, "", "out_dir");
SwitchArg pocxpSwitch("p", "pocxp", "Power cycle cameras");

vector<Arg*> xorlist;
xorlist.push_back(&lutArg);
xorlist.push_back(&lutOutArg);
xorlist.push_back(&pocxpSwitch);
cmd.xorAdd(xorlist);

cmd.parse(argc,argv);
```

Comment: Wwhat is TCLAP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer from TCLAP support, it's cannot be done with the current version.